# C# Scale image and save it to folder vs. scale and use in runtime

Tags: c#

First of all, sorry for the title but I don't know how to explain it better.
Here is my question. I'm scaling images, check for duplicates and watermark them. The interesting thing is that when I save them to a "/temp/" folder, the whole process is faster than just scaling and using them while they're loaded in the memory.

This is the code that I'm using for scaling:

```
private static Bitmap ScaleImage(string pathToImage, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pathToImage);
    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);

    return bmp;
}
```

Then I just assign the scaled images to variables:

```
Image imageLeft = ScaleImage(tempImage1, 48, 48);
Image imageRight = ScaleImage(tempImage2, 48, 48);
```

... and compare them.

So what bothers me is why this is slower than saving all scaled images in a folder and then do the comparsion?